# Transforming data type in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a "Copy" step in my Azure Data Factory pipeline which copies data from CSV file to MSSQL.

Unfortunately, all columns in CSV comes as `String` data type. How can I change these data types to match the data type in SQL table.

[image]

Here is how the data is available in CSV file.

[image]

I would like to change data type of `WIPStateKey` to `Integer` and `ReportDt` to `Timestamp`. I do not seem to find an option to achieve this.

Comment: Which column data type you want to change? Or what's destination table column type?

Comment: @LeonYue I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as you said "all columns in CSV comes as String data type".

But when using  a copy active, choose the csv file as the source, we can import the schema and change the column data type.

I created a demo.csv file for test:

[image]

I copy data from my demo.csv file to my Azure SQL database.
[image]

During file format setting, we can change the column data type:
[image]

Table mapping:
[image]

Column mapping:
[image]

Copy completed:
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps